# How to access node.js app deployed to Heroku

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, heroku

I want to deploy my node.js app to Heroku but after watching several tutorials and reading through the documentation, I cant see how I would get and post to the hosted node.js app. The node.js app sends and receives data from my webpage which worked successfully when hosted locally but I want to try and host it on a server.

How can I access the file posted on Heroku?

Comment: You'll be given a URL after you install it.

Comment: Will that URL be the port that I send and receive data from? Sorry I am new to using servers.@wostex

Comment: @UnknownDeveloper already answered this, @Gordon. Set your port as `prosess.env.PORT`

Answer (score 0):

When you first set up a Heroku instance you get to choose a URL which ends on .herokuapp.com. By visiting that URL you can access your Heroku instance. To use a Heroku port just use `process.env.PORT`

Comment: But couldn't that be linked to any port hosted on Heroku?@UnknownDeveloper